# Monotone Property of Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be a monotone matrix i.e. $A^{-1}\geq 0$. We have if $Av\geq 0 \implies v\geq 0 \forall v \in \mathbb{R}^n$
Can we have the other side of implication? I tried but not able to get it.

Comment: See [Monotone matrix - Examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_matrix#Examples).

Comment: Yes, as the proposition $\forall v \in \Bbb{R}^n, v \ge 0$ is *false*, so the implication $$\forall v \in \Bbb{R}^n, v \ge 0 \implies \cdots$$ is *true*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. E.g. $A=\pmatrix{1&-2\\ 0&1}$ is monotone, because $A^{-1}=\pmatrix{1&2\\ 0&1}\ge0$, but $A\pmatrix{0\\ 1}=\pmatrix{-2\\ 1}\not\ge0$.